# PhoneGap handleOpenUrl and Android

Tags: android, cordova

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    final String invokeString = getIntent().getDataString();
    if(invokeString != "" && invokeString != null) {
        this.sendJavascript("handleOpenURL('" + invokeString + "');");
        System.out.println(invokeString);
    }
}
```

I found this code on this website: http://blog.cttapp.com/p/phonegap-handleopenurl-for-android/.

It won't execute handleOpenURL, and I know this, because it would otherwise redirect the page.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Seems like webview is not ready for it yet.

Here is how I got that to work: override the `onMessage` function, because it seems to be ready to listen to you by then:

```
@Override
public Object onMessage(String id, Object obj) {

    if (id.equals("onPageStarted")) {

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getDataString()!= "" && intent.getDataString()!= null){
            String url = intent.getDataString();
            this.sendJavascript("handleOpenURL('" + url + "');");
        }

    }
    return super.onMessage(id, obj);
}
```

I found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/L63TTsngjiU).

Comment: The only worked for me after I changed the id condition to "onPageFinished", which obviously triggers later. Also you should take that url variable definition outside of the conditional so you don't have to call intent.getDataString() 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and wanted to share a *much* worse (as far as I can tell) solution for anyone who might not want to build Cordova themselves...

Right before the line

```
this.sendJavascript("handleOpenURL('" + url + "');");
```

Add this

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
   } catch (Exception e) {
   // nothing
   }
```

I'm aware this isn't optimal but I really didn't have time to extend Cordova itself...

ALSO: since the link in the (much better) answer above is missing a little info (some forum messages in the solution thread have been deleted), [here's](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/c509c8e7e53bdd0dd78481c6f0bdada8bf0800ee/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java) the file whose onMessage you'll have to override...good luck!